# Retaining scss inheritance with child template of Cassiopeia

Tags: styling, cassiopeia

I've been reading the child theme docs and other Cassiopeia - specific documentation but can't find best practices for retaining the template.scss so that I can extend scss mixins and variables. I've created a child to the Cassiopeia template so my best guess is that I have to create my own custom.scss file in media/templates/site/cassiopeia_child/scss, then @import the template.scss file from the parent template location, and then finally edit the index.php in the child template to include custom.scss.

Does this logic sound good or is there a better way?

To be clear, I would like to avoid adding a user.css file since I won't be able to import the parent's scss.